# Why can't `std::priority_queue::top()` return a non-const reference?

Tags: c++, stl, c++14, priority-queue

I need to maintain a priority queue `Q` of large objects (of type `T`). Since these objects are expensive to copy, I would like to be able to retrieve a writable object with `auto h = std::move(Q.top())`. But I can't do this since `std::priority_queue<std::unique_ptr<T>>::top()` returns only a const reference. Why? (And is there a simple workaround?)

Comment: Modifying an element in a priority queue would destroy its property of being a priority queue.

Comment: @molbdnilo Maybe then there's a `pop()`-like method that gives me back my object?

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes I have. Just making sure I would be justified in casting away const or whether I'm missing something.

Comment: You can derive from priority_queue, then you will get access of `c` member (it is protected) which is underlying container. Then you can do with `c` whatever you want. But I disadvise this.

Comment: Will writing to this object modify its place in the queue?

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes possibly, but I just want to get my object back out of the queue.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the large objects as `unique_ptr<T>` in the priority queue. The thing to note is that `queue.top()` returns a `const unique_ptr<T>&`, which means that the `T` itself *isn't* `const`. So you can do this:

```
T obj(std::move(*queue.top()));
queue.pop();
```

Edit: Since your `T` doesn't have a move constructor, I'd just bite the bullet a little bit and use a `std::shared_ptr<T>`:

```
std::priority_queue<std::shared_ptr<T>, ...> queue;

// fill queue

// No need for anything special. 
std::shared_ptr<T> ptr = queue.top();
queue.pop();
```

Comment: Ok, so if `T` doesn't have a move constructor (which is why I had put it in a `std::unique_ptr`) I should use `std::unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<T>>`?

Comment: I'd just use a `std::shared_ptr<T>` in that case. You only need the *shared* part to copy it (the pointer, not the object) out of the queue, but it would save the headache of trying to deal with pointers to pointers and so on. I'll edit my answer to include that.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your large object to additional structure which will have a field to be used by custom compare function, this member should not be affected by *move* operations, for example it should by some plain data type like `int`:

```
struct BigObject {
    std::unique_ptr<int> data;
    int forCmp;
};

struct Cmp {
    bool operator()(const BigObject& lhs, const BigObject& rhs) {
        return lhs.forCmp < rhs.forCmp;
    }
};
```

after `move(queue.top())` inner order of queue cannot be broken. Moved instance of BigObject still has a valid value of `forCmp` used by comparator.

Then inherit from `priority_queue`, by doing this you will have the access to `c` underyling container, and add `front` method:

```
template<class T, class Cmp>
struct Wrapper : std::priority_queue<T,std::vector<T>,Cmp> {
    T& front() {
        return this->c.front();
    }
};
```

the use:

```
Wrapper<BigObject,Cmp> q;
BigObject bo;
bo.forCmp = 12;
q.push(std::move(bo));

BigObject i = std::move(q.front());
```

[Full demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7YAMG5)

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit from `priority_queue` and write `T pop()` to hide `void pop()`

```
template <typename T>
T fixed_priority_queue<T>::pop() {
    std::pop_heap(c.begin(), c.end(), comp); 
    T value = std::move(c.back());
    c.pop_back();
    return value;
}
```